# What is the difference beetween "div>p" and "div p" in CSS

Tags: html, css

`div>p` selects all `<p>` elements where the parent is a `<div>` element and `div p` selects all `<p>` elements inside `<div>` elements. This is what W3schools says but i dont know what is the difference. If an element is inside another one is child and the other is parent. I dont see the differences.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Example:

```
<div>
    <span>
        <p>...</p>
    <span>
</div>
```

`div > p` won't select that paragraph, but `div p` will. In other words, the first selector is parent-child, while the second is ancestor-descendant.

Answer (score 1):

div >p select direct child of div which is p whereas div p select every p inside div no matter if p is child of other dom with in div. Also you can say div>p is css 3 selector.

Answer (score 1):

`div > p` means "Select all <p> elements that are children of a <div>", e.g. only the first

will be selected here:

```
<div>
  <p>...</p>
  <div>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

`div p` means "Select all <p> elements that are descendants of a <div>", e.g. both <p> elements would be selected.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is whether you want it to be the "immediate child" (`>`) of the parent, or allow for it to be the "immediate child", but also "grandchild" or "great-grandchild" (and so on) too ().

Answer (score 0):

With `div>p` you refer to all `<p>` that are directly  childs of a `<div>`.

```
<div>
    <p>Selected!</p>
    <a><p>Not Selected</p></a>
</div>
```

With `div p` you refer to all `<p>` that are into a `<div>` no matter the depth

```
<div>
    <p>Selected!</p>
    <a><p>Selected!</p></a>
</div>
```